# Show keyboard in Libgdx

Tags: android, keyboard, libgdx, textfield

I am trying to show the keyboard on a android device when a textfield is clicked in LibGdx. But as far as I can see have to detect when the textfield is clicked manually and then show the keyboard by calling `Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true)`?

This is the code I have so far:

```
    textfield= new TextField("", skin);
    textfield.setSize(300, 50);
    textfield.setPosition((SCREEN.WIDTH/2) - textfield.getWidth()/2, 0);

    //Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true);

    //Gdx.input.getTextInput(this, "SOME TITLE" "TEXT");

    textfield.setTextFieldListener(new TextFieldListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char key)
        {
            if (key == '\n')
            {
                textField.getOnscreenKeyboard().show(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The keyboard is normally shown automatically when a text field gains focus or is touched. You shouldn't have to do it manually. Have you set your stage as the input processor?

Comment: @nEx.Software Tried doing it like you mentioned, and that seems to works great. Provide your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved from comment on original post (and edited to be more answer-like):

The keyboard is normally shown automatically when a text field gains focus or is touched. You shouldn't have to do it manually. This requires the stage to be registered as the input processor via this call:

`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`